# .NET Most efficient way to replace placeholders text with actual values?

Tags: .net, replace

I've a a template text (a newsletter text) to be sent to many users; in the text there are some placeholders, such as {{firstname}}, {{lastname}} and so on.

What would be more efficient for replacing placeholders with actual values,
`.Replace(..)` concatenation or `RegExp`, or other methods?

.NET language.

Comment: You also have string.Format() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you will be calling `.Replace()` multiple times, it's probably more efficient to use `StringBuilder.Replace()`, since `StringBuilder` is [optimized for multiple modifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w.aspx).

If you have flexibility in the format of the placeholders, I think [DotLiquid](http://dotliquidmarkup.org/) would be a good candidate for this.  They probably have optimized the text processing for this scenario, although it also supports other advanced syntax so there might be overhead there.

Answer (score 1):

I recently test-compared standard dotnet ways

1. `string.Replace.Replace.Replace` - least memory efficient but slightly quicker than `StringBuilder`
2. `StringBuilder.Replace.Replace.Replace` 2x times memory efficient to `string.Replace` but a bit slower
3. `string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", x, y, z)` is about 20% less memory efficient vs `StringBuilder` but 2x+ quicker than `string.Replace.Replace.Replace`